# LoadBalancing with several servers

Tags: load-balancing

I'm hosting several web projects and I'm thinking about to start balancing the load, but actually, I got no clue on how to do it.

My idea was:

Make HDD's sync on all servers, so all servers have the same HDD
Balance the load with Crossroads
Do you think that's a good idea? It would cost alot of space on the HDD, is it worth?

Thanks

Finn

Comment: I think you really, REALLY need to google "load balancing for web servers" and read up on the technology. You haven't asked an answerable question (there's zero useful information provided), and you're approaching load balancing from a very... "unusual" angle -- Learn a bit more about how things are usually done, then come back and ask us if you have questions :-)

Answer (score 2):

You're actually asking two questions.

**Load balancing of HTTP traffic**

A good tool to use is haproxy. I find it very worthwhile to use because of its light resource usage, versatile configuration, excellent logging and good "live" UI.

You can run it on one machine and distribute HTTP connections to various backends based on a configurable strategy (like round-robin, or more preferably: least open connections).

**Deploying your application on multiple hosts**

Just syncing the harddrive will likely not be the solution. Unfortunately you only mention "web projects". Does that mean static HTML? Code? Databases?

Most applications aren't written in a manner that they can operate on a "shared filesystem" because they would step on each other.

The architectural pattern that is normally used for making web applications scale is called "shared nothing" so they can run without this kind of syncing.

I find the "12 factor app" a good handbook for this pattern: http://www.12factor.net/processes it also references the Wikipedia article on the topic: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shared_nothing_architecture